# Filewriter-Printwriter not working with jar on linux

Tags: java, linux, jar, filewriter, printwriter

I have this pieace of code:

```
    Calendar ca=Calendar.getInstance();
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("Locations_Elapsed time iterations.txt", true);
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw);              
    ca.setTime(new Date());                      
    a++;
    pw.write("user " + a + " " + ca.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND));
    pw.println();
    pw.close();
```

It works fine when I run it with netbeans (ofcourse). I want to execute it on a server away from my machine which works with Linux, so I make a jar file to do this.

The problem is that it is not writing anything. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Any exception thrown?

Comment: Nop! No exceptions thrown

Comment: Looks like there is a space in the file name you are trying to write to. Remove that and try again to see if it works

Comment: You haven't told us anything about how you're creating the jar file or how you're trying to execute it. Are you sure your code is running *at all*? Are you able to get other code (e.g. writing to the console) to run?

Comment: And when you say nothing is being written, does it create the file?

Comment: @VishalKamat Thank you very much Vishal! It works indeed. Cheers :)

Comment: Thank you all for your interest problem solved!

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment yet: can you give a little more detail about what happens when you launch the jar? How do you launch it? Where is the file you are calling stored?
At first glance I would think that you don't have a exception handling and thus you cannot see that the file hasn't been found or something on the like.
By the way, I suggest you (for testing purposes) to use [Files.write](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2885173/how-to-create-a-file-and-write-to-a-file-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

It might be that the user who is running the program does not have write permission in the directory in which the file `Locations_Elapsed time iterations.txt` is to be created.